# PHP: use for loop/foreach inside array_filter

Tags: php

I tried to use for-loop/foreach inside `array_filter()`. but the for loop/foreach doesn't work inside `array_filter()`. How can I use for-loop/foreach inside `array_filter()`?

```
$bookingData = array_values(array_filter($jsonBooking, function($bookingItem) {
    foreach ($orderData as $orderItem) {
        if ($bookingItem['order_id'] === $orderItem['id']) { 
            return $bookingItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer given does solve the problem, even while it looks like there are much better ways of doing this. But without more context from your side, I don't care to speculate. Also, your `return bookingItem` should have had a `$`, and that should have given an error for "undefined constant". Along with the fact that `$orderData` was undefined. Are you developing without error reporting on?

Answer (score 1):

Callback inside `array_filter` must returns `bool` (as condition to filter), be but you return an object.
This should work.

```php
$bookingData = array_values(array_filter($jsonBooking, function($bookingItem) use ($orderData) {
    foreach ($orderData as $orderItem) {
        if ($bookingItem['order_id'] === $orderItem['id']) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

UPDATED: don't forget `use` statement

Comment: `$orderData` is unknown inside filter. // GG I reversed my vote